# For each sentence in List 1, find how many times items from List 2 appear. How can I do this in Python?

Tags: python, lambda

I have a list of words, for example:

```
list_of_words = ['car', 'motorcycle', 'tree']
```

I also have a list of sentences, for example:

```
list_of_sentences = ["I have a car, but I don't have a motorcycle", "I like elephants but I don't like lions"]
```

**Goal:** For each sentence in `list_of_sentences`, I want to find *exactly* how many words from `list_of_words` it includes. In this particular example the return should be:

```
[2, 0]
```

**Note:** In practice, my `list_of_sentences` and `list_of_words` lists contain thousands of items so ideally, the solution should be fast.

Comment: How is a word defined here? e.g. case sensitive, with weird punctuation, multiple words etc. e.g. what would this return? `"My car, i like my Car and other cars too, and   my tree! Yes tree tree; trees and treehouses ...      car"`

Answer (score 1):

Edited:  Another option, maybe importing more libraries, and taking into account the examples that  @Chris_Rands exposed, could be:

```
import collections
from operator import itemgetter
import re
list_of_words = ['car', 'motorcycle', 'tree']
list_of_sentences = ["I have a car, but I don't have a motorcycle", 
                     "My car, i like my Car and other cars too, and   my tree! Yes tree tree; trees and treehouses ...      car",
                     "I have carpal tunnel syndrome"]

count=[sum(itemgetter(*list_of_words)(collections.Counter(re.findall(r'\w+', sentence)))) for sentence in list_of_sentences]
print(count)
```

Output:

```
[2, 5, 0]
```

Comment: "I have carpal tunnel syndrome" contains a car by your definition

Comment: Yeah you are right, I didn't think in that possible sentence, sorry... Just edited the answer. Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 1):

You should probably tokenize the sentences first to remove unwanted punctuation signs, and then find the [`set.intersection`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#set) with the list of words:

```
from nltk import word_tokenize

list_of_words = set(['car', 'motorcycle', 'tree'])
list_of_sentences = ["I have a car, but I don't have a motorcycle", 
                     "I like elephants but I don't like lions"]

[len(list_of_words.intersection(word_tokenize(s))) for s in list_of_sentences]
# [2, 0]
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, where *`\b` allows you to perform a “whole words only” search.*

```
import re

list_of_words = ['car', 'motorcycle', 'tree']
list_of_sentences = ["I have a car, but I don't have a motorcycle", 
                     "I have carpal tunnel syndrome"]

search_ = re.compile("\\b%s\\b" % "\\b|\\b".join(list_of_words))

print([len(search_.findall(x)) for x in list_of_sentences])
```

Answer (score 0):

heres another way to do it with loops:

```
list_of_words = []
list_of_sentences = []
num_words = []

for i in list_of_sentences:
    val=0
    for j in list_of_words:
        if j in i:
            val = val+1
    num_words.append(val)
print(num_words)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can split the words of each sentence using `re.split('[^\w\']', sentence)` into a list, transform that list to a set, and then apply a set intersection (with the `&` operator) between that and a set of the words in `list_of_words`. The `result` list will have the length of the resulting set. Something like:

```py
import re


list_of_sentences = ["I have a car, but I don't have a motorcycle",
                     "I like elephants but I don't like lions"]
list_of_words = ['car', 'motorcycle', 'tree']

set_of_words = {*list_of_words}

result = [len({*re.split('[^\w\']', sentence)} & set_of_words)
          for sentence in list_of_sentences]
# result list contains: [2, 0]
```